# Pyparsing - matching the outermost set of nested brackets

Tags: nested, brackets, pyparsing

I'm trying to use pyparsing to build a parser that will match on all text within an arbitrarily nested set of brackets.  If we consider a string like this:

```
"[A,[B,C],[D,E,F],G] Random Middle text [H,I,J]"
```

What I would like is for a parser to match in a way that it returns two matches:

```
[
  "[A,[B,C],[D,E,F],G]",
  "[H,I,J]"
]
```

I was able to accomplish a somewhat-working version of this using a barrage of originalTextFor mashed up with nestedExpr, but this breaks when your nesting is deeper than the number of OriginalTextFor expressions.

Is there a straightforward way to only match on the outermost expression grabbed by nestedExpr, or a way to modify its logic so that everything after the first paired match is treated as plaintext rather than being parsed?

update:  One thing that seems to come close to what I want to accomplish is this modified version of the logic from nestedExpr:

```
def mynest(opener='{', closer='}'):
    content = (empty.copy()+CharsNotIn(opener+closer+ParserElement.DEFAULT_WHITE_CHARS))
    ret = Forward()
    ret <<= ( Suppress(opener) + originalTextFor(ZeroOrMore( ret | content ))  + Suppress(closer) )
    return ret
```

This gets me most of the way there, although there's an extra level of list wrapping in there that I really don't need, and what I'd really like is for those brackets to be included in the string (without getting into an infinite recursion situation by not suppressing them).

```
parser = mynest("[","]")
result = parser.searchString("[A,[B,C],[D,E,F],G] Random Middle text [H,I,J]")
result.asList()
>>> [['A,[B,C],[D,E,F],G'], ['H,I,J']]
```

I know I could strip these out with a simple list comprehension, but it would be ideal if I could just eliminate that second, redundant level.

Answer (score 3):

Not sure why this wouldn't work:

```
sample = "[A,[B,C],[D,E,F],G] Random Middle text [H,I,J]"

scanner = originalTextFor(nestedExpr('[',']'))

for match in scanner.searchString(sample):
    print(match[0])
```

prints:

```
'[A,[B,C],[D,E,F],G]'
'[H,I,J]'
```

What is the situation where "this breaks when your nesting is deeper than the number of OriginalTextFor expressions"?

Comment: it was breaking when adding on a parseAction to change what's happening with the interior text (doing some custom text formatting).

The bigger question I'm trying to figure out now is how to stop the single result from being wrapped in a nested list, without having to use a list comprehenson (because my parsed text is HUGE and I'd like to avoid one more for loop).

Comment: ungroup, perhaps?